# Installing dependencies in Elixir

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Is there a way to install a dependency for an Elixir project directly through the command line using `mix` or `mix hex`?

I am aware of the option for searching the `hex` registry via

```
$ mix hex.search httpoison

Package    Version  URL
httpoison  0.11.0   https://hex.pm/packages/httpoison
```

However, I am looking for something like

```
$ mix hex.install httpoison
```

which will modify my `mix.exs` file, adding the name and most recent version of the dependency to the `deps` function and the application name to the `applications` list and then run

```
$ mix deps.get
```

to pull and compile the dependency.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are looking for something similar to `npm install --save`, then this does not exist in Elixir. You install things by adding them to `deps:` in the `mix.exs` file in your project then running `mix deps.get`.

The other way you may wish to install certain applications is via a mix archive allowing this mix task to be run globally. One example of this is `phoenix.new` for creating new phoenix applications which can be installed by running:

```
mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/releases/download/v0.16.1/phoenix_new-0.16.1.ez
```

Comment: does this mean I can't have some global environment that I can write small one-off scripts against? For example, as a long time rubyist I have many single-file utility scripts that don't use bundler but often have dependencies that assume a standard set of global gems.